# Can I set $? in a test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ipc, ruby-1.9.2

I have a Ruby program. That program goes

```
IO.popen('blah') { ... }
if $?.success?
   ...
```

Most of the time `$?` is a `Process::Status` object. Occasionally it's nil instead. That crashes the program. Easy enough to fix, right?

But I want to write a test.

I have the technology to mock the IO.popen call, but I can't set `$?` to nil since it's read-only. How can I set `$?` to nil?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can't set this. Via C-code global variables can actually expand to a function call, and that's what happens here (`rb_last_status_get`)

The easiest would be to define a method that is easier for you to stub, for example

```
module Process
  def self.last_status
    $?
  end
end
```

Then use `Process.last_status` instead of $?. You can obviously stub this out in specs and it's a little more readable if you get confused between all the magic globals.